# setInterval after textarea input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to save a textareas information after the input changes and after 2 seconds.

I tried it using this code:

```
jQuery('#textarea').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        //save
     }, 2000);
});
```

but it wasn't very effective, as the there seemed to be some sort of infinite loop that I had created.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Then you need to clear previous timer if there are new changes in `textarea`. For example something like this:

```
jQuery('#textarea').on('input propertychange paste', function() {

    // Clear previous timeout
    if ($(this).data('timeout')) {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    }

    // Set up new one
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
        //save
     }, 2000));
});
```

Comment: ...and probably grab `this` or the value to a local before the `setTimeout`, although one could use `$("#textarea")` again I suppose.

Comment: Thanks that has worked well. In your code, I think you meant to put `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`...